# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm developing a Discord bot but I have some problems, Whenever I write any word in chat I see so many errors. Find my code below,

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var set = require('./settings.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log('Ready!');
   client.user.setActivity ("Deneme");
});


client.on('message', message => {

const role = client.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Pascal');
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
member.roles.add(role);

if (message.content === 'Hi') {

    message.channel.send('Hi!');
}
});

client.login(set.token);
```

and that's my error code on terminal;

[Visual Studio Code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVD9D.png)

Comment: `client` does not have a `roles` property. You'll need to discover why.

Comment: change `client` to `message` and it'll work.

Comment: i did edit like this const role = message.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Pascal');
but is still same

Comment: oh my bad, put in a guild as well. `message.guild.roles.cache.find`

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca its worked but i have new errors as usual 
`member.roles.add(role);
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`

I often see it as 'undefined'. How can I solve this in general. Do you have information?

Comment: Make sure that `member` is actually found before continuing. Try a `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do

`const role = client.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Pascal');`

Try this code instead

`const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === rolename);`

As for your other error about the member, use this following code to initialize the member.

`const member = msg.mentions.members.first();`